# Is it possible to change a database (schema) name in AWS Athena?

Tags: amazon-athena

I created a database and some tables with Data on AWS Athena and would like to rename the database without deleting and re-creating the tables and database. Is there a way to do this? I tried the standard SQL alter database but it doesn't seem to work.

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there is no way to do this according to [this official forum thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=245343). You would need to remove the database and re-create it. However, since Athena does not store any data by itself, deleting a table or a database won't impact your data stored on S3. Therefore, if you kept all the scripts that create external tables, re-creating a database should be fairly quick thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Athena doesn't support renaming database. You need to recreate database with a new name.

You can use **Presto** which is an open source version of Athena and Presto supports more DDL queries.